# jQuery dynamic form, how get the value with dynamic id's?

Tags: php, jquery

I am new in jQuery and I have to do a dynamic form with two selects, in one select I need to make that if the user choose the option let's say B another select appear but if he choose A then it doesn't show, the problem is that I can get to every element in the form, I do the form with a PHP for and then pass the variable to the id's so it gets something like this:

```
<select id="edocivil<?php echo $x ?>" class="textbox" name="edocivil<?php print $x; ?>" >
```

$x been the number of the field, I need to get the value of that field so if it B it shows these other select that is in a div, this is how:

```
<div id="regimen<?php echo "$x"; ?>" style="display:none;">
```

and what I do is have a hidden field with the value of $x so I can get it with jQuery but I can't do it I need help please, I leave the jQuery script and the hidden field thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //asÌ es como se crean las funciones jQuery. solo cree

var id_edo= $(this).next(".numero_id_edo").val();
alert(id_edo);
$("#edocivil"+id_edo).change(function(){ //se ejecuta con el evento onChange  


 var val = $("#edocivil"+id_edo).val()

if(val =="B")
{
    $("#regimen"+id_edo).show();  
}
else
{
    $("#regimen"+id_edo).hide();  
}

});//change
});//ready
```

the hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="numero_id_edo"  id="numero_id_edo" value="<?php echo $x; ?>" class="numero_id_edo">
```

I tried to make it the most understandable way, I am really new to this of Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok if i have understood well you can do it like this, first get the `value` of hidden field so that we have the `$x`

```
var $x = $("#numero_id_edo").val(); //here we get the value of hidden field or inother words $x
```

now on the basis of this we can get the selected value of dropdown

```
$("#edocivil"+$x).change(function(){

alert($(this).val());

});
```

**edit**

by assuming you have multiple hidden fields on the page you can get there values like

```
var idArr=[];

$("input:hidden").each(function(){

idArr.push($(this).val());
});

alert(idArr.length);

for (v in idArr )
{
alert(idArr[v]);
}
```

look at this fiddle hopefully you will get the idea http://jsfiddle.net/3nigma/hAcuF/1/

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but it only gives me the first value the other  values don't so I can only show the first div and the others I can't

Comment: ok so you have more than one hidden fields in the page?? each referring to the field number??

Comment: Yes there are x number of fields been x the number of partners that the user put on the other page

Comment: what i wanted to ask was, for every form field you are specifying a hidden field?

Comment: i have not fully understood your scenario, but you can have a hidden field for every form field or you can make a comma separated string of x number of partners and assign to the value of a hidden field like `value=1,2,3,4,5` and then get its value through jquery and iterated over it, you can assign some unique class to every field and access the field through that class remember an element can have more than one class so you can assign some unique class to every `form field` and then access the field through that class

Comment: Ok I think I understand that but can I do a if inside the for? Or It will be wrong?

Comment: @3nigma let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1745/discussion-between-apz2000-and-3nigma)

Comment: question, what's this: idArr.push($(this).val());? I don't know

Comment: it pushes the value into the array idArr